# How to check javascript number range?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How following if condition true for `ids=1`

```js
var ids = 1;

if (9 <= ids <= 14) {

  console.log(9 <= ids <= 14)

}
```

I want it to be true only if the value of ids between 9 and 14. Appreciate any help understanding how JavaScript operators work when checking range.

Comment: if(ids >= 9 && ids <=14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't chain comparison operators like that. You have to do each comparison separately and use AND (&&) or OR (||).

```
var ids = 1;
if (9 <= ids && ids <= 14) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check with two conditions and one logical AND, because the first condition returns a boolean value and this is compared with the other value.

```js
var ids = 1;

if (9 <= ids && ids <= 14) {
    console.log('in range');
} else {
    console.log('not in range');
}
```